# How can I detect the variable used by student (STACK on Moodle)?

Tags: stack, moodle, maxima, wxmaxima

I use a set to describe a line in the space, such as (Maxima, STACK on Moodle)

```
te:{[x,2*x-3,4*x+5]}        (1)
```

that means: line with direction (1,2,4) , and (0,-3,5) belongs to the line.
But the student can describe the same line with a completely different set, ie

```
se:{[1+u,2*u-1,9+4*u]}      (2)
```

to compute the point and vector in (1), we do

```
ros:listify(te);
po:ev(ros,x=0);
vec:ev(ros,x=1)-po;
```

but, since the question is made in an STACK question on a moodle questionnaire, *I must automatically detect which variable was used in (2)*.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Try `listofvars` to get the list of variables in an expression. Also, try `subst([somevar = somevalue], someexpr)` instead of `ev(someexpr, somevar = somevalue)`, because `subst` is more predictable -- `ev` has very strange behavior in some ways. (Sorry about that; it is likely too late, 50 years on, to fix that.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @RobertDodier
 I never found the command listofvars in the internet. And wondered, how STACK does to recognize that?
And for the advice between ev and subst.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to help. I guess I don't know what is the list of functions which STACK recognizes, maybe there's some documentation. By the way, if there's only one substitution, you can write `subst(somevar = somevalue, someexpr)`, i.e. without the `[ ]`. But if you have two or more substitutions, then you can put them in a list, `subst([a = 1, b = 2, c = 3], ...)` or whatever. (I mixed up those two cases when I wrote the comment before.)

Comment: Yes, @RobertDodier, STACK recognizes that, in the same way as Maxima, there are other which STACK doesn't recognizes, and others that only STACK implements, like `rand_with_prohib(infLimit,supLimit,[list of prohibs])`